# Ant - Execute specific target from one target and not from other

Tags: ant, conditional-statements

I can run my build file from two targets as below

```
<target name="makeMinificationTarget" depends="inheritedTarget" />
<target name="skipMinificationTarget" depends="inheritedTarget" />
```

However, these both targets internally calls "inheritedTarget" and this "inheritedTarget" internally calls "makeMinification" target.

Following is "inheritedTarget" and "makeMinification"

```
<target name="makeMinification">
    <echo message="makingMinification...">
</target>

<target name="inheritedTarget" depends="makeMinification"/>
    <echo message="compileFiles">       
    <echo message="ExecuteFiles">
</target>
```

My question is i want to skip execution of "makeMinification" target from

this call `<target name="skipMinificationTarget" depends="inheritedTarget" />`

And

let it happen if we call `<target name="makeMinificationTarget" depends="inheritedTarget" />`

How can I achieve this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? Using "antcall" and passing the parameter. Instead of using "depends"

```
<target name="makeMinificationTarget" >
    <antcall target="inheritedTarget">
        <param name="Minification" value="true"/>
    </antcall>
</target>       

<target name="skipMinificationTarget" >
    <antcall target="inheritedTarget">
        <param name="Minification" value="false"/>
    </antcall>
</target>   

<target name="inheritedTarget" >
    <if>
        <equals arg1="${Minification}" arg2="true" />
        <then>
            <antcall target="makeMinification"/>
        </then>
    <else>
        <!-- Do something else-->
     </else>
    </if>
    <!-- Do other stuff -->
</target>

<target name="makeMinification" >
    <!-- Do something -->
</target>
```

Comment: The other day I implemented the exact structure as you have provided above, and yes, I have done it by passing parameter to antcall.... anyways, thanks !!!